# How do I make this div go to the bottom of another div?

Tags: html

Making a website for school, once again, and I'm trying to make my test div goto the bottom of my content div, but cant seem to get it working.

http://ditcs.neocities.org/ is the live website if you could possibly help me. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add     `margin-top: 440px;` to `#test`

The better option is to do this:

```
#test {
    width: 970px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    height: 160px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    bottom: 0;
}
#content {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: 14px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 972.8px;
    height: 600px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #8467D7;
}
```

Comment: Cheers lad. Much appreciated :)